# Sharepoint Project - VS2010 Communication error while deploying

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I am getting:
"A communication error has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state"

While deploying a sharepoint solution from visual studio 2010.  It has worked before, as I am still in testing.  No code has changed, not sure if it has something to do with settings or memory.

Any ideas or guidance on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The application pool is probably hanging after things like attemping to call code while a breakpoint is active and so on, an IISRESET should fix this.

Comment: So just a reset of the IIS server? or is there a way to manually clear the application pool?

Comment: There is, you can go to the IIS Manager, find the application pool related to your sharepoint Web Application and recycle the process.

Comment: Make sure you mark things as the answer, otherwise it hurts your reputation on the site.